# Cant use getRef()?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Can anyone explain why this is saying I can not use getRef to get the position that is being clicked? From everything I have looked up, this should work and for some reason it is not.

```
public class DeleteChoiceListFragment extends Fragment {

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mRestReference = mRootRef.child("restaurants");

List<String> listofrest = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView restaurantListView;
ListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;


public DeleteChoiceListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_selection_list_frag, container, false);
    restaurantListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);

    restaurantListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Restaurants>(getActivity(), Restaurants.class, R.layout.individual_restaurant_name_nocheckbox, mRestReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Restaurants model, final int position) {
            TextView restName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restname);
            restName.setText(model.getName());

            listofrest.add(position, model.getName());
        }
    };

    restaurantListView.setAdapter(restaurantListAdapter);
    restaurantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Firebase itemtoremove = restaurantListAdapter.getRef(i);
            //I get an error here saying I can't use .getRef()
            itemtoremove.removeValue();


        }
    });
    return view;

  }
 }
```

Comment: there is not method `getRef()` wether for `ListAdapter` nor for it´s parent class `Adapter`. `getRef()` seems to be a method of `FirebaseListAdapter` https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html

Comment: I am trying to use it on a FirebaseListAdapter - restaurantListAdapter is a Firebase List Adapter

Comment: no it isn´t ...your declaration is `ListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;`...this is definetely no `FirebaseListAdapter`

Answer (score 2):

You've *declared* restaurantListAdapter as a `ListAdapter`. Even when you put a `FirebaseListAdapter` object into that field, you can only access method that are defined on `ListAdapter`.

The solution is to also *declare* the field as a `FirebaseListAdapter`:

```
FirebaseListAdapter restaurantListAdapter;
```